# React Redux: Data from src/components not updated on localhost

Tags: reactjs, redux, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with data in my src/components and src/reducers. When I make changes there, I can't see them on localhost:3000.

On localhost I see:

"This is a book title
This is the book description

usd. 499.99"

And my data I see "Lord of the Rings"

What can I do to make these changes visible on localhost?

https://github.com/ivanradunkovic/bookstore

For example:

```
// BOOKS REDUCERS
export function booksReducers(state={
    books: 
        [{
            _id: 1,
            title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring',
            description: 'A meek Hobbit from the Shire and eight companions set out on a journey to destroy the powerful One Ring and save Middle-earth from the Dark Lord Sauron.',
            price: 20.01
        }, 
        {
            _id: 2,
            title: 'This is a second book title',
            description: 'This is the second book description',
            price: 325.25
        }]
}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "GETT_BOOK": 
        return {...state, books:[...state.books]};

        case "POST_BOOK": 
        // let books = state.books.concat(action.payload);
        // return {books};
        return {books:[...state.books, ...action.payload]};

        case "DELETE_BOOK":
        // Create a copy of the current array of books
        const currentBookToDelete = [...state.books]
        // Determine at which index in books array is the book to be deleted
        const indexToDelete = currentBookToDelete.findIndex(
          function(book){
            return book.title === action.payload;
          }
        )
        //use slice to remove the book at the specified index
        return {books: [...currentBookToDelete.slice(0, indexToDelete), ...currentBookToDelete.slice(indexToDelete + 1)]}

        case "UPDATE_BOOK":
        // Create a copy of the current array of books
        const currentBookToUpdate = [...state.books]
        // Determine at which index in books array is the book to be deleted
        const indexToUpdate = currentBookToUpdate.findIndex(
          function(book){
            return book._id === action.payload._id;
          }
        )
        // Create a new book object with the new values and with the same array index of the item we want to replace. To achieve this we will use ...spread but we could use concat methos too
        const newBookToUpdate = {
          ...currentBookToUpdate[indexToUpdate],
          title: action.payload.title
        }
        // This Log has the purpose to show you how newBookToUpdate looks like
        console.log("what is it newBookToUpdate", newBookToUpdate);
        //use slice to remove the book at the specified index, replace with the new object and concatenate witht he rest of items in the array
        return {books: [...currentBookToUpdate.slice(0, indexToUpdate), newBookToUpdate, ...currentBookToUpdate.slice(indexToUpdate + 1)]}
      }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: how you use this reducer in code?

Comment: is this a typo? `switch(action.type) { case "GETT_BOOK": ` there are two T's there

Comment: also if you could post more code, such as where are you using this reducer. Also you should consider putting your state in a variable called something like `const initialState = {}`

Comment: I mess up on github something rn. Can you please chek code in this repo? Thanks for your help.

https://github.com/ivanradunkovic/bookstore

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way, which also involves a lot less code, is to store your data as an object graph, keyed by the book id.

So you initial state would like like

```
books: {
  1: {
       id: 1,
       title: 'Lord of the rings',
       ...the rest
     },
  2: {
       id: 2,
       ... the rest
     }
}
```

The in your reducer function, you can use the id key to find or update items a lot easer

```
case 'UPDATE_BOOK':
  return {
    ...state.books,
    [action.payload.id]: action.payload
  }

case 'DELETE_BOOK'
  const next = {...state.books}
  delete next[action.payload]

  return {
    ...state,
    books: next
  }
```

I realise this isn't exactly a solution to your problem, I'm just giving you another way to store your data, which means you don't have to keep filtering on arrays everywhere.

And to just return the values is simply `Object.values(state.books)`

Comment: @sina-farhadi I approved your edit, but if there were other properties in the state object, they wouldn't get returned. Maybe my original state object didn't really show that very well.

Comment: Still nothing. 

I want to edit code that when I make changes I can see them in localhost. Now I have wrong data all the time.

Comment: Like I said, this isn't a solution, this is giving you another way to think about your data structure.

Comment: Yeah I know. I can change data structure, but problem is still there. When i change data in footer I still see old data.

Comment: Can you see if your actions are getting dispatched and your reducer is running? I'm unble to pull your repo and run it at the moment